# How to calculate average grade from data in SQL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ado.net-entity-data-model

In database I have a table `Grade(stGrade, ndGrade, rdGrade, Avg)`.

How I can calculate `Avg` in asp.net project, and `stGrade, ndGrade, rdGrade` can be null.

Example, if `Grade(80, 90, null)`then `Avg` = 85. If `Grade(80, 90, 100)` then `Avg` = 90.

In view, my code:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Grades){
        <tr>
            <td>@item.stGrade</td>
            <td>@item.ndGrade</td>
            <th>@item.rdGrade</th>
            <th>@item.Avg</th> 
        </tr>
    }
```

And in controller:

```
 public ActionResult Result()
    {
        db = new GradeManagementEntities();
        Student st = db.Students.Find(Session["id"].ToString());
        return View(st);
    }
```

How can I use Average()? In class maybe, right?

```
public Nullable<double> stGrade { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> ndGrade { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> rdGrade { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Avg{get; set;}
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
```

But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: use a linq `.Average()` query.

Comment: Your code is not clear... In View code, you are using `Model.Grade` but in your controller code you are sending a `Student` to the view... And what is the class in the last code section ? Student ? Grades ?

Comment: My flault, particularly Student class have a foreign key idStudent of class 'Grade(idStudent, stGrade, ndGrade, rdGrade)'. First in view: references @model Assignment_GradeManagement.Models.Studnet. Sorrry because I'm newbie.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Result()
{
    db = new GradeManagementEntities();
    Student st = db.Students.Find(Session["id"].ToString());
foreach(var s in st)
{
int total=0,avg=0;
if(s.ndGrade != null)
{
total++;
avg+=s.ndGrade;
}
if(s.stGrade!= null)
{
total++;
avg+=s.stGrade;
}
if(s.rdGrade!= null)
{
total++;
avg+=s.stGrade;
}
if(total>0)
{
s.avg= avg/total;
}
}
return View(st);
```